# ElasticSearch - Chain or relate results of one response to another using msearch

Tags: elasticsearch

With the pandemic COVID19 lurking around, hope all of you guys are fine

Just a quick question, with the past year, I've been tasked with certain endpoints that require Elasticsearch queries. I'm now in the optimization part, and just so happened I stumble upon the **Multi Search** API or commonly known as **msearch**.

Now with the idea of **msearch**, I've thought I could lessen the number of searches that I make to our ES servers. Before, I'm making 2 search queries, and now my aim is to have 1 msearch query to lighten the endpoints' loading time.

Is there a way for the first aggs response of **msearch** be related to the next aggregations? I mean, is there a way for me to chain or get the response of the first aggs in msearch then pass it to the next aggregations in run-time?

Example Scenario:

**FIRST AGGS**

I'm getting the MAX VALUE of a certain field

```
"aggs" => [
    'MAX_SVALUE' => [
        'max' => [
            'field' => 'latest.soc_mm_score'
        ]
    ],
]
```

**SECOND AGGS**

Using the *max* value above

> Please note, the **$mxs** here, is a PHP based array, it contains the max values form the **FIRST AGGS**

```
"aggs" => [
    "SVALUE" => [
        "terms" => [
            "script" => [
                "source"=>"
                    double temp = Double.parseDouble((((doc['latest.soc_mm_score'].value * 10) / ".$mxs[$platforms[$p]].").toString()));
                    return temp;
                ",
                "lang"=>"painless"
            ],
            "size"=> 10000
        ]
    ]
]
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The idea of `_msearch` is to either split up heavy searches or query various index combinations in a single go

```
{ "index": "INDEX_NAME_1", "type": "TYPE_NAME_1" }
{ "query": { "match_all": {}}}
{ "index": "INDEX_NAME_2", "type": "TYPE_NAME_2" }
{ "query": { "match_all": {}}}
```

Now, these searches have different contexts and to put it bluntly, "don't know about each other". So no, *you cannot* use the result of one inside of the next one at runtime.

You'll have to perform the first request, get the max and then run your other aggregation.